# PhpExcel, как правильно заполнить таблицу этим массивом?

Tags: php, excel, phpexcel

У меня есть массив такого вида:

```
$arr = [['checkTitle' => 'Проверка наличия файла robots.txt', "result" => "true",
                'stateTitle' => 'Состоние',   'recommendTitle' => "Рекомендации",
                'stateResult' => "Файл есть", 'recommendResult' => "Нету"],];
```

И такая таблица:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Заполняю вот так:

```
foreach ( $this->createArray() as $key => $item ) {
        $currentColumn = 0;
        $this->sheet->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($currentColumn, $startLine, $key + 1);

        $this->sheet->getStyle("A2")->applyFromArray($this->textAlignCenter());

        $this->document->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells("A" . $startLine . ":" . "A" . ($startLine + 1));
        $this->document->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells("B" . $startLine . ":" . "B" . ($startLine + 1));
        $this->document->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells("C" . $startLine . ":" . "C" . ($startLine + 1));

        foreach ( $item as $value ) {
            $this->sheet->getStyle("A")->applyFromArray($this->textAlignCenter());
            $currentColumn++;
            $this->sheet->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($currentColumn, $startLine, $value);
        }
        $startLine += 3;
    }
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно это сделать? Думала по-другому переписать массив:

```
$arr = ['checkTitle' => 'Проверка наличия файла robots.txt', "status" => "true",
                'info' => ['title' => "Файл есть", "Рекомендации" => "Нету"]],];
```

Но и так не вышло :с

В общем, в идеале должно быть так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Загрузите вашу таблицу и скиньте ссылку. И почему не PhpSpreadsheet?

Comment: @VikiMayson, я еще не научилась загружать таблицу. Пока что просто вывожу её на страницу

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все можно сделать намного проще. Для это у библиотеки уже есть готовый метод.

```
<?php
include 'Classes/PHPExcel.php';
include 'Classes/PHPExcel/Writer/Excel2007.php';

$xls = new PHPExcel();
$xls->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
$sheet = $xls->getActiveSheet();
$sheet->setTitle('Stackoverflow');

$sheet->setCellValue("A1", '№');
$sheet->setCellValue("B1", 'Название проверки');
$sheet->setCellValue("D1", 'Статус');
$sheet->setCellValue("F1", 'Текущее состояние');

$sheet->mergeCells('B1:C1');
$sheet->mergeCells('F1:G1');

$sheet->getStyle('A1')->getAlignment()->setHorizontal(PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::HORIZONTAL_CENTER);

$arr = [
    ['number' => 1, 'checkTitle' => 'Проверка наличия файла robots.txt', "result" => "true",
    'stateTitle' => 'Состоние',   'recommendTitle' => "Рекомендации",
    'stateResult' => "Файл есть", 'recommendResult' => "Нету"],

    ['number' => 2, 'checkTitle' => 'Проверка наличия файла robots.txt', "result" => "false",
        'stateTitle' => 'Состоние',   'recommendTitle' => "Рекомендации",
        'stateResult' => "Файла нету", 'recommendResult' => "Нету"],

    ['number' => 3, 'checkTitle' => 'Еще один текст', "result" => "false",
        'stateTitle' => 'Состоние',   'recommendTitle' => "Рекомендации",
        'stateResult' => "Файл есть", 'recommendResult' => "Есть"],
    ];


$xls->getActiveSheet()->fromArray(
    $arr,
    NULL,
    'A2'
);

$objWriter = new PHPExcel_Writer_Excel2007($xls);
$objWriter->save(str_replace('.php', '.xlsx', __FILE__));

echo " Скачать сгенерированный файл <a href='test.xlsx'>ЖМИ</a>";
?>
```

Результат
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо, но всё не так просто. Будь у меня такие ячейки, сама бы написала) но посмотрите, пожалуйста, изображение таблицы. Я приложила его к вопросу. У меня половина таблицы merged, а половину (состояние, рекомендации и текущее состояние) — нет

Comment: Приложила ещё одно изображение